# Select an item from a list in JSTL

Tags: forms, jsp, hidden-field, jst

In the following JSP , i have a list which i am iterating and printing with an additional button

**JSP**

```
<form action="servlet">
                                <table border="2">
                                    <th>Req no</th>
                                    <th>username</th>
                                    <th>Leave Type</th>
                                    <th>No of Days Requested</th>
                                    <th>Status</th>
                                    <th>Approve</th>
                                    <c:forEach var="pro" items="${userRequest}">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><c:out value="${pro.reqno}"></c:out></td>
                                            <td><c:out value="${pro.user_name}"></c:out></td>
                                            <td><c:out value="${pro.leave_Type}"></c:out></td>
                                            <td><c:out value="${pro.no_of_days}"></c:out></td>
                                            <td><c:out value="${pro.status}"></c:out></td>
                                            <td><input type="submit" value="approve"></td>
                                            <td><input type="hidden" name="approve" value="yes"></td>
                                            <td><input type="hidden" name="reqno" value="${pro.reqno}"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </c:forEach>
                                </table>
                            </form>
```

[image: output screen]

If i click on the **approve** button in my form , the hidden fields takes the value of all the rows . I need to post reqno from individual row alone (i.e) the row which i click the button. Please suggest me an idea .
  Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to change Approve button from 'submit' type to 'button' type.
2. You remove 'hidden' input in TR.
3. Sample codes:

   ```
   <tr>
       <td><c:out value="${pro.reqno}"></c:out></td>
       <td><c:out value="${pro.user_name}"></c:out></td>
       <td><c:out value="${pro.leave_Type}"></c:out></td>
       <td><c:out value="${pro.no_of_days}"></c:out></td>
       <td><c:out value="${pro.status}"></c:out></td>

       <td><input type="button" class="btnApproveReq" data-reqno="${pro.reqno}" value="approve"></td>
   </tr>
   ```
4. use jQuery to handle onclick:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {

            $(".btnApproveReq").click( 
                function() {
                    var selectedReqNo = $(this).attr("data-reqno");

                    var urlToApprove = "/yourApp/req/approve?reqno=" + selectedReqNo;

                    // CALL AJAX to urlToApprove 

                    // Call this If you want to remove TR after AJAX success

                    // $(this).parent() --> TD
                    // $(this).parent().parent() --> TR
                    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
                }
            );
       });
   </script>
   ```

Comment: Are u sure it will take the input from that row alone , i.e a single element from list

Comment: Sure. You can test it.

Comment: is there any way to remove the row once if we post it to the servlet??

Comment: Can u pls explain this path , i am using netbeans IDE "/yourApp/req/approve?reqno=" , And what is "req","approve" and reqno here??

Comment: "/yourApp/req/approve?reqno=" is my FAKE url. This url is URL service that handle approve function.